# Python How to prevent multiprocessing zombies when the kernel is terminated

Tags: python, multiprocessing, zombie-process

recently I have a problem with the zombie processes when using multiprocessing in Python.

I have a script who creates several processes(workers) as well as an another process(printer). The workers will produce msgs into a queue and the printer need to print all the msgs in the queue.

The problem is that normally the workers need to work for hours. But sometimes after launching the script, I'd like to change some code and relaunch the script. If I wait until the job finished, there will be no zombie since I use join(). But if I shut down the kernel directly (since ctrl+C doesn't work for my spyder), all the processes(zombies) are still working.

I tried to use the `os.ppid` but it seems that the ppid doesn't change.
I tried `p.daemon = True` but it doesn't work neither.

So I'd like to ask is there a way to make sure that if I shut down the kernel, all the processes will terminate themselves and there is no zombies in the system.

Thanks, the example code is :

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time

def f(num, q):
    for i in range(100):
        q.put('f: num=%d\n'% (num,))
        time.sleep(10)
def g(q, filename):
    while True:
        with open(filename, 'a') as f:
            if q.qsize() > 0:
                item = q.get()
                if item == None:
                    break
                else:
                    f.write(item)
def main():
    filename = './log.txt'
    q = Queue()
    workers = [Process(target=f, args=(i,q)) for i in range(10)]
    printer = Process(target=g, args=(q,filename))
    for p in workers:
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()
    printer.daemon = True
    printer.start()
    for p in workers:
        p.join()
    q.put(None)
    printer.join()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "shutting down the kernel"? Which command do you actually issue?

Comment: In fact, I use the Spyder IDE and I click the square button "stop the current command" for Ipython console or a triangle button "Kills the current process" for Python console. Or, I close the Spyder directly. The zombie processes are always there. I used Atom too and, if I run the script and close Atom later, it's the same situation.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Ah... Windows :( But I will use linux to run the file later

Comment: @Yunguan Just FYI, that's not 'shutting down the kernel'. If you really _had_ shut down [the kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)), your entire computer would be effectively dead.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan Ah... I would like to say the python console. Thanks :)

Comment: @AkshatMahajan I don't believe "kernel" is incorrect as it's used in the question. Spyder uses iPython/Jupyter, which utilizes various kernels (https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels) as backends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The children processes are not released because the parent gets terminated abruptly without the possibility of cleaning up. Therefore, the `daemon` flag is of no use.

I would not terminate processes with children with an IDE as it is probably not considering such use cases. I'd rather rely on the OS facilities.

On Windows you can use the `Taskkill` command altogether with the `/T` parameter. See the [taskkill documentation](https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html).

On Linux you could use the `pkill` command with the `-P` parameter. [Pkill manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill).

One last resort would consist of intercepting the SIGTERM signal and rerouting it as SIGINT. But I would not recommend this.

```
import os
from signal import signal, SIGINT, SIGTERM

def handler(*_):
    os.kill(os.pid, SIGINT)

signal.signal(SIGTERM, handler)
```

This is a hack and I'm not even sure it will work on Windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So it seems that the only way is to clean those zombies manulally ? I tried Taskkill and it works very well :) For now, I can't very weel understand the code of SIGTERM but I will do some search later. Thanks again !

Comment: If the answer was useful, please mark it as correct so other people can easily find it. If your IDE allows customisations (Atom does) you could add a shortcut. If you don't fully understand the SIGTERM alternative, stay away from it :). It's a hack anyway.

Comment: OK ! Thanks you a lot !! :) Sorry for the lateness.